# Jquery tabs + aspx gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am trying to use jquery ui theme (tabs) in aspx.
    $(function () {
            $('#tabs').tabs();
        });

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">    
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab s2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        tab-1
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        tab-2
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        Gridview is here
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Height="31px" Text="Button" 
             onclick="Button2_Click" />
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

now i am calling a function button2_click doing some operation on Gridview but i am getting the error
Control 'GridView1' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExportToExcel(GridView1, "HElloWorld");
    }
    private void ExportToExcel(GridView gv, string filename)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename + ".xls");

        Response.Charset = "";

        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);


        gv.RenderControl(hw);



        string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";

        Response.Write(style);
        //Response.Write(GetMessage());
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        // Response.Write(GetFooter());
        Response.Flush();

        Response.End();

    }
```

error is coming at gv.RenderControl(hw);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are missing one div closing tag. put `</div>` just before `</form>` and it should work.

Googling it got me this, just override the method Page.VerifyRenderingInServerForm Method, as follows:

`public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        return;
    }`

n thats it. You will be free of that error...

Comment: div was missing...i corrected that...but still the same error

Comment: I dont know, at first i did now know what community wiki was, and after creating it i went to meta to check it, and now i dont know how to remove it.